# NullPointerException при вставке в map

Tags: java

Есть фрагмент кода в котором я хочу обрабатывать данные, которые вводит пользователь в формате

```
Кошельков Захар Брониславович,105
Дьячков Нисон Иринеевич,88
Иванов Варлам Якунович,88
Старостин Ростислав Ермолаевич,50
Ярилова Розалия Трофимовна,29
Соколов Андрей Сергеевич,15
Егоров Алан Петрович,7
END
```

```
Map<String,Integer> name_age = null;
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(in);
String line;
while(!Objects.equals(line = input.readLine(), "END")){
    System.out.println(line);
    String[] line_delimited = line.split(",");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line_delimited));
    name_age.put(line_delimited[0], Integer.parseInt(line_delimited[1]));
}
```

Но по какой-то причине после считывания первой строки возникает NullPointerException, я пробовал различные способы считывания данных, через Scanner тоже, но во всех случаях возникает исключение.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

20 строчка это:

```
name_age.put(line_delimited[0], Integer.parseInt(line_delimited[1]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"по какой-то причине" ? `Map` что, из воздуха должен возникнуть?

```
Map<String, Integer> name_age = new HashMap<>();
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```